# Is the rationale that SLOAD is expensive to distribute paying for storage away from SSTORE and onto SLOAD?

Tags: gas

Storage on Ethereum is a limited resource. It makes sense that SSTORE is quite expensive. But, reading from storage cannot be a limited resource in the same way storage is. Is the reason SLOAD is quite expensive, that it actually pays for storage (disincentivizes wasting storage) rather than the actual cost of reading from storage?

The cost of SLOAD has gone up from 50 to 200 in 2016, 200 to 800 in 2019, and 800 to 2100 in 2020. The reason often cited is denial of service attacks, that the time it takes to access storage requires the cost increase. But is there also other reasons that are less mentioned?

If it is just about execution time, does it take 2100/30 = 70x longer to do a SLOAD of a 256-bit value, than a keccak256() of a 256-bit value? Or, does it take 10x longer to do a keccak256() than an ADD operation? Hashes like sha/keccak do hundreds of ADD operations, besides other operations like rotations or XORs. I can't intuitively see that they should only be 10x more expensive than ADD, or, 70x less expensive than SLOAD.

*This ties into my question about why redoing a hash of a specific pre-image a billion times is cheaper than reading a stored value of the hash of that pre-image a billion times. It really seems like it isn't.*

Some context. If SLOAD price is to disincentivize storage, a sort of improvised "state rent", it seems like that breaks when the storage is 256-bit vs redoing keccak256 for a pre-image a billion times.

SSTORE, maybe 20000 GAS. Then, SLOAD, 800, times a billion. 800 * 10^9, 800 billion GAS to store 256-bit. Vs 30 * 10^9, 30 billion to redo the same hash for a specific pre-image. I think that seems broken.